# Is it possible to enable HTTP basic authentication in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, authentication

A URL such as `http://username:password@example.com/` does not work in Internet Explorer, as explained in the Microsoft Knowledgebase article “[Internet Explorer does not support user names and passwords in Web site addresses](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489)”. I can’t find a proper workaround for this. I want just a simple link in a HTML document which works.

#### The purpose of the exercise:

We have a website, with fairly secure cookie-based login. We have standard stats packages (Webalizer and AWStats) which use HTTP authentication. I want to give the administrator of the site a quick link to the stats. The link, which includes the password, will be available only to a logged in administrator. It’s no great security risk.

Comment: That's because there isn't a workaround.

Comment: Okay. I'll give up on that idea, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username:password@example.com construct was removed as a security feature.  Storing passwords in plain text is a bad idea to start with, and this form of the url was a *frequently used* attack vector for phishing attacks.  The article you link to lists some work-arounds... can you not just prompt the user to enter a password?

If you give a little more details about what you're doing, it's possible a better solution may be found.

Answer (score 7):

Per the Knowledgebase article, this can be enabled by setting the `DWORD` for iexplore.exe to 0 in:
`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE]`.

Doing so will enable you to browse to URLs using the syntax `[user]:[password]@[url]`.