# open popup with basic auth in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, basic-authentication

MS Edge does not seem to open basic auth dialog when opened it in a popup.
Any workaround?

example:

```
window.open("http://papermashup.com/demos/php-auth/index.php","_blank")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell us which release you are using currently?

I find that there is an issue in Edge. This issue is corrected in 17736.rs5_release or later. So if you are not using this version then try to update may help you to solve your issue.

Reference:

[No credential prompt for basic auth](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/18341748/)

Comment: I used `Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the username/password in the URL:

> http://username:password@papermashup.com/demos/php-auth/index.php

Comment: this way I get error `A security problem occurred.`

Comment: Ah, if I remember correctly browsers started to depreciate this functionality. Not sure if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620207/is-it-possible-to-enable-http-basic-authentication-in-internet-explorer/17332138